# Convert Scientific Notation to decimal in Azure Data Flows

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an input file that has a column with mixture of decimal and scientific notation values. I have tried to convert the column using toDecimal, which seems to work for the non-zero decimals and the scientific notation values, but zeroes are converted *to* scientific notation.  Is it possible to keep the zero values as plain zeroes?

[image: Converting column to decimal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like by default 0/0.0 is converted to exponential value when using the decimal function. One way is to convert decimal to string.

`case(Value == 0.0, toString(0.0),toString(toDecimal(Value,20,10)))`

[image]