Scientific Notation in Azure Datafactory Dataflows
When reading data using a Dataflow, I am finding that either very large or very small numbers are being turned into scientific notation automatically. The data being read is being read from a single line JSON file which reads fine, however when flattening the data, the notation switch seems to be occurring, ie 3568291023 is turning into 3.568291023E9.
The format of the data being read is as follows:

"values":[[1111,"dog","cat","drink","Water (ML)"0,2909888293,1234599283,2232341,21352,23253,2.98,3.07,3.25,3.36,3.4,3.53,3.59,"","Water","Water Data.csv","2021-04-22 21:32:33.734"],

and the input projection on the source is as a complex data type, as it is inputted as nested JSON. The derived columns following the source are (for example) year = Values[1], animal_1 = Values[2], etc.
I am currently flattening the data and deriving into columns. In an attempt to fix this issue, I have tried converting the respective columns into Decimals or Doubles to change the existing string format ie Data column Data_C1 derives to Data_C1_Dec using the expression toDecimal(Data_C1, 20,10) which fixes the issue with the large numbers, however this then causes another issue where all 0 value rows in the column then become 0E10, bringing back the scientific notation issue.
Is there a way to convert all string number values back to the raw number form without the data flow auto changing the form into scientific notation?


You can change the string data to original numeric value by changing the type in projection.
In source transformation, click the projection tab.
Click the import projection.
Change the type of the column from string to long or double based on the requirement.


This would help the data to be read properly in correct data type.

Hi, thanks for this, however I don't believe this would work as the input for the data is as a single line JSON string, and the data coming in is being brought in as a complex data type so the data type isn't able to be defined yet

You can define the complex data type also in projection tab.

Can you share the sample json so that i could help in writing the expression for complex type

I ended up with an answer using a variation from this post in the end but thank you for your help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71601856/convert-scientific-notation-to-decimal-in-azure-data-flows
To complete this, I used
case(value == "0", toString(0.0),toString(toDecimal(value,20,10)))
and then a second derive column to trim the trailing 0's when present

You can add this as answer in this thread itself. This approach might help the community who faces the similar issues.
